# How do I delete k8s Jobs and its pods by client-go?

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

I tried to delete my jobs with a LabelSelector by [client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go):

```golang
cli.BatchV1().Jobs("default").Delete(context.TODO(), name, metav1.DeleteOptions{})
```

And the job was deleted successfully, but the pods of it didn't!

If I delete this job by `kubectl`, the pod it created would be deleted automatically.

How could I delete jobs with its pods simply by `client-go`?

Comment: Somehow you need to enable cascade deletion or DeletePropagation to delete child objects like pods.

Comment: Yes, I found that what I need to do was set `PropagationPolicy` in `DeleteOptions`. Now when I delete a job the dependents would be deleted automatically. Thanks.

Comment: sounds like we know an answer to this question we haven't provided to the page

Answer (score 3):

you need to set the `PropagationPolicy` field in `DeleteOptions` to `Background`. This ensures that the Job and its child Pods are deleted.

```
import metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"

//...

backgroundDeletion := metav1.DeletePropagationBackground

err := cli.BatchV1()
       .Jobs("default")
       .Delete(context.TODO(), name, metav1.DeleteOptions{
           PropagationPolicy: &backgroundDeletion, 
       })
```

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/495 this issue can also help you with. Here are the docs! https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1#DeleteOptions